# ¿Como recuperar variables enviadas por Angular en PHP?

Tags: php, angular, post, get

Estoy intentando mandar un dato por get desde un servicio Angular 5 a una API en PHP.

La forma en que lo mando es así:

```
public getMembers$(id): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(this.URL + 'read_records.php?id=1');
}
```

La variable this.URL viene del environments y no es problema. La API es alcanzada por el servicio, eso lo veo en la llamada en network.

El problema es que en la API no logro recuperar la variable id enviada. Lo he probado con `$_GET` y con `file_get_contents("php://input")` y no hay manera.

¿Cuál es la forma correcta de recuperar variables en la API cuando se mandan desde Angular? Para el método `http.post` si me funciona el `php://input` (siempre que lo que mande vaya serializado en un json), pero hay más tipos de envíos (envio por post de ficheros, envios por get, o put o delete).

¿Como puedo recuperar esos datos en PHP?

Comment: y el código de la api??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No veo que muestre el código de su API pero...

Prueba con:

```
$request = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

Puedes poner esto al comienzo de tu script PHP.  `$request` entonces será un objeto `stdClass` con los datos como propiedades.

```
$id = $request->id;
```

Alternativamente, si prefiere trabajar con él como una matriz asociativa, use:

```
$request = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);
```

y acceder a los datos como:

```
$id = $request['id'];
```

Espero le sirva de ayuda!

Comment: Si, gracias. El problema es que funciona con envíos por post, pero no por get. Cuando el envío se hace por get, esto no funciona. Existe alguna otra envoltura que funcione para get? Gracias.